# Reload MKAnnotation in mapView - Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a problem, I have to constantly reload my view as I have to be able to view within this function the value of a UISlider that is constantly updated through an animation made through a function that manages the touch of a button. I noticed that when I open the map this slider value always remains fixed at the initial value, despite the latter having changed. How do I update the annotations? I have read on other posts about deleting and re-adding them:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
         if (annotation is MapEarthquakeAnnotation) {
             let mapEqAnnotation = annotation as! MapEarthquakeAnnotation
             var view: MKPinAnnotationView
            print("MARIOCASH",Int(sliderTime.value))
             if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: mapEqAnnotation.identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
             {
                 // Recycle old view
                 dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                 view = dequeuedView
             }
             else
             {
                
                 // Create new view
                
                view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: mapEqAnnotation.identifier)
                view.canShowCallout = true
                view.pinTintColor = UIColor.brown
                 
                 let infoButton = UIButton(type: .infoDark)
                 infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                 view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton
             }
             return view
        }else if annotation is MapSeismometerAnnotation
        {
            if let annotation = annotation as? MapSeismometerAnnotation
            {
                var view: MKPinAnnotationView
                /*
                // Recycle old view
                if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotation.identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
                {
                    dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                    view = dequeuedView
                }
                else
                { */
                    // Create new view
                    view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotation.identifier)
                    view.canShowCallout = true
                    view.pinTintColor = UIColor.green
                    view.image = UIImage(named: "pin-verde")
                    if annotation.identifier == "redpin"
                    {
                        var count = 0
                        var c = 0.8 //valore iniziale dell'aplha per l'opacità del pin rosso
                        view.image = UIImage(named: "pin-rosso")
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1,repeats: true)
                        {t in //ogni secondo questo timer cambia il valore dell'alpha del pin che sta vibrando
                            view.alpha = CGFloat(c)
                            count += 1
                            c -= 0.15
                            if count == 5
                            {
                                t.invalidate()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                return view
                //}
            }
            return nil
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your `viewFor annotation` method and a little more info on how you set up the view?

Comment: @SanzioAngeli sorry I entered the code wrong. I just edited, see now

Comment: I doubt what I am about to recommend is the proper way to do this, so I will not write it as an answer, however you do not HAVE to dequeue a reusable view. I would recommend trying to create these views separately, say in a dictionary of `[MKAnnotation: UIView]`, and then return the respective view in `viewFor annotation`. Issue is that whenever you dequeue a reusable view, it resets the view. This is most likely why your views are not updating properly.